# .htaccess url rewrite external link

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a music site I am working on and was wondering how can I rewrite an external link to make it look as though I am serving content locally?

basically, I want to load external mp3's but visually make it look like i'm serving them myself..

so say I am requesting the following file:

```
http://www.external-site.com/uploads/user/test.mp3
```

I want to be able to access it as:

```
http://www.mysite.com/uploads/user/test.mp3
```

without a redirect being seen in the url bar

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with `.htaccess` - all you can do with `mod_rewrite` and its kin is either treat the URL differently *internally*, or send a redirect *externally*, ie. visible to the end user because you actually redirect the browser. To completely transparently serve external content as if it's coming from your site, you have to actually serve it from your site, so you'll have to write a script in PHP or whatever you're using to fetch the external content, and 're-serve' it to your own user (in PHP for example via `die(file_get_contents('external-url'))`).

Keep in mind that this means your own server will have to download **and** upload the file in question, so you'll incur double bandwidth costs and some server load, while an external redirect has neither.

Comment: I recall seeing something before where you could do: `http://external-domain.mywebsite.com/file-from-ext-domain.mp3`; where as external-domain would point to an external site. how can that be achieved?

Comment: It will have the same restrictions, or the remote website has to be misconfigured to allow listening to that domain. Highly unlikely, it's just not how the internet works: you can always see where you're downloading from.